# Convert AWS GOES Data to GeoTiff

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, amazon-web-services

I need to convert netCDF files from AWS's GOES data into GeoTIFF. My end goal is to use these as raster layers in GeoServer. I have used GDAL to warp a GeoTIFF into EPSG 4326 so for now I just need to get it into a GeoTIFF. I tried using gdal_translate with the command:

```
gdal_translate NETCDF:"OR_ABI-L2-CMIPF-M3C02_G16_s20180640000387_e20180640011153_c20180640011226.nc":CMI test2.tif
```

This gives me an image, but opening it with an image viewer just shows a white background with a completely black circle. I've also tried using Python with the code:

```
# Required libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import pdb

# Path to the GOES-R simulated image file
path = '/home/brian/projects/aws_goes_testing/OR_ABI-L2-CMIPF-M3C02_G16_s20180640000387_e20180640011153_c20180640011226.nc'

# Open the file using the NetCDF4 library
nc = Dataset(path)

# Extract the Brightness Temperature values from the NetCDF
data = nc.variables['CMI'][:]

# Show data
plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

This gives me an image I want but I'm not sure how I can save the data variable as a GeoTIFF. Obviously I can use plt.savefig() but this isn't what I want since it will include the axis and everything from the figure I don't want.

Comment: For anyone trying to do this while being able to use other libraries, try rioxarray

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to kind of work. When I put the geotiff in geoserver and load it onto the cesium globe it doesn't line up properly, so something isn't write with the projection, but the general idea is there:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Required libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr
import numpy as np
import pdb
import subprocess

# Path to the GOES-R simulated image file
path = '/home/brian/projects/aws_goes_testing/OR_ABI-L2-CMIPF-M3C02_G16_s20180661800402_e20180661811169_c20180661811241.nc'

# Open the file using the NetCDF4 library
nc = Dataset(path)

# Extract the Brightness Temperature values from the NetCDF
data = nc.variables['CMI'][:]
#it automatically fills null values to 65535
data.data[data.data == 65535] = -1
normData = data.data * 255
normData[normData == -255] = 255
normData8 = normData.astype('uint8')

nx = data.data.shape[0]
ny = data.data.shape[1]
latLon = nc['geospatial_lat_lon_extent']
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = [latLon.geospatial_westbound_longitude, latLon.geospatial_southbound_latitude, latLon.geospatial_eastbound_longitude, latLon.geospatial_northbound_latitude]


xres = (xmax - xmin) / float(nx)
yres = (ymax - ymin) / float(ny)
geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)
normData = data.data/data.data.max() * 255
dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('myGeoTIFF_unwarped2.tif', ny, nx, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)    # specify coords
srs = osr.SpatialReference()            # establish encoding
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                # WGS84 lat/long
dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt()) # export coords to file
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(normData8)   # write r-band to the raster
dst_ds.FlushCache()                     # write to disk

dst_ds = None
# Show data
#plt.imshow(data, cmap='Greys')
#plt.show()
nc.close()
```